# C - While and IF statements - Trying to timeout after X time

Tags: c, if-statement, timer, while-loop, serial-port

I am having difficulties with the below code;

```
int i = 0;
int x = 0;
int ch ;
int n;

    while((i < sizeof(buffer) - 1) && (x < (TIMER_FREQ*30)))
    {
        //getkey_serial0 returns either a (int)character or 0 if nothing on                                            
        //UART0
        if((ch = getkey_serial0) == 0)
        {
             x++;    //Increment X as there is nothing being received.
        }
        else
        {
            if(ch == '\n')
            {
                 n++;
            }

            if(n < 8){    //Yes I can simplify this but for some reason
            }             //I only just noticed this :/ Anyway, it is
            else{         //just here to avoid saving info I don't need
                 buffer[i] = ch ;
                 i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

As the input it is reading in is the results of a wireless scan the number of entries scanned can vary greatly, and so I need to be able to avoid infinitely looping. 
Originally I just read up to 11 \n's but this was rubbish as I kept missing SSID's which I needed, so I decided I needed some sort of timer or method to help me break after X amount of time.

TIMER_FREQ is defined as 10.

Clearly I am doing something stupid so any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated.
I generally prefer suggestions to help me try and think out the problem as opposed to fixed code posts :) I always seem to miss something simple despite my best efforts!

Thanks

EDIT: I should mention, this is on an embedded system (ARM7)

Comment: Just a thougt... really there is no timer there, just TIMER_REQ iterations. The time needed for a loop depends of the CPU clock+number of instructions. I find it possible with modern CPUs that you are reading the same first character received TIMER_REQ times, because there has been no time to receive another character yet.
EDIT: Sorry didn't see that you only increment the index when you read something. Are you sure that getKey_serial0 cleans the character read from the UART?

Comment: @SJuan76 well to be honest I added an LED flash to the segment where I increment X and interestingly it didn't flash. I didn't pay much attention to this as I assumed that I made some silly error with the LED code but if not then that would indicate that it never returns 0, which should be impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really mean:

```
if((ch = getkey_serial0) == 0) { ...
```

Or do you actually mean:

```
if((ch = getkey_serial0()) == 0) { ...
```

If the latter, this is why your program never returns zero as you are giving it a function pointer. Does your program have many warnings at build?

Comment: Oh.. Right.. Lesson #43, when copying and pasting frequently, ensure you remember to replace any brackets that may have been lost along the way. Although not as useful on discussion of timers and the like - tagged as answer as it is technically "the answer" and turns the above into working code. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You should have access to a general purpose timer interrupt -- commonly called sys_tick().

The general practice in such "bare metal" applications is to configure the interrupt to fire every *n* milliseconds  (10 ms is frequently used on my Cortex M3).  Then, have the ISR update a counter.  You'll want to ensure the counter update is atomic, so use a 32-bit, properly-aligned variable.  (I'm assuming your processor is 32-bit, I can't recall for certain).  Then your "application" code can poll the elapsed time as needed.

BUT - this timer discussion might be moot.  In my ARM9 applications, we tie an interrupt to the UART's receive buffer.  The associated ISR captures the keystroke and then performs any buffer management.  Is that an option for you?

Comment: Hi, I do have an interrupt that I have configured for the UART but this is not active at this point in the code, because I have a few events that need to be handled it isn't (At least I think) suitable to read in. Again, I still can't be sure if I interrupt each character to a buffer when to perform any actions on the buffer, which is what led to me to consider some sort of timer or alarm. Thanks for the suggestion, I will have a look into the sys_tick function :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to time things, look into [time()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time). It will let you see the system's wall clock, so you can determine if too many seconds have elapsed.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly this is on an embedded system (ARM7) and so I don't have access to this function.

Comment: @Draineh: Are you using an operating system? Do you have a global timer anywhere? Most embedded systems I've worked with kept track of time somehow.

Comment: No I am coding the firmware directly and using a basic bootloader to load the updates. I have access to the RTC? I had some thoughts that I could somehow use this to generate an interrupt after x time but that didn't amount to much

Comment: @Draineh: If you can read the RTC, or perhaps a ticks-since-power-on-counter if ARM7 has one, you'll get better and more reliable times than sticking an increment in your loop. Generating an interrupt seems like a bad fit for something like this.